# How change `setup.py test` to use different Pypi server?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Currently I have `~/.pypirc` file like this:

```
[distutils]
index-servers=
    mypypi

[mypypi]
repository = http://192.168.100.101:8080/simple
username = awesome_user
password = awesome_pass
```

Also I have `/etc/pip.conf` file:

```
[global]
index-url = https://192.168.100.101:8080/simple/
allow-external = true
allow-unverified = true
```

In [setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies) documentation we can read:

> When your project is installed, either by using EasyInstall, setup.py
>   install, or setup.py develop, all of the dependencies not already
>   installed will be located (via PyPI), downloaded, built (if
>   necessary), and installed.

I can successfully deploy a package but problem is when trying to do `setup.py test`, it trying to get dependencies from `pypi.org` not `mypypi`.

```
running test
Searching for fancy_super_lib
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/fancy_super_lib/
Couldn't find index page for 'fancy_super_lib' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for fancy_super_lib
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('fancy_super_lib')
```

How to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Simply create file `~/.pydistutils.cfg` and put this content:

```
[easy_install]
index_url = http://192.168.100.101:8080/simple
```

This will use Your Pypi server instead global pypi.org.